# Implementing delete confirmation box on Delete click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, confirm

I have a list item. When user clicks on "X", for any list item, I need to show a confirmation box for delete which says *Are you sure you want to delete this item?* along with Yes/No buttons.

If user clicks on Yes, the item should be deleted. My code for deletion works perfectly fine. I am just not sure how to show a window.confirm in the html part. Here's my code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: activeList">
    <li data-bind="click: function () { $root.delete('Item', $data); }">
        <a data-bind="click: function () { $root.DeleteFile('Item', $data); }">
            <img src="../../DeleteCross.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

you can not do this on html part. You need to display this on javascript part.

```
<li data-bind="click:$root.delete('Item', $data)">
    <a data-bind="click:$root.DeleteFile('Item', $data)">
        <img src="../../DeleteCross.png" />
    </a>
</li>
```

In your viewmodel create function like this

```
self.delete = function() {
    var confirm_delete = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    if (confirm_delete) {
        // deletion code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen an example in some forums and tried the same. But this doesnt work for me. Please suggest if the code is incorrect or if there is any other better approach.
<ul data-bind="foreach: activeImageList">
<li class="icn add" data-bind="click: function () { if (confirm('Delete, really?')) { $root.deleteFile('Image', $data); } }">
<a data-bind="click: function () { $root.DeleteFile('Image', $data); }">
<img src="../../CSS/images/RedCross.png" />
</a>
<b data-bind="text: title"></b>
</li>
</ul>
Thanks